# I am trying to swap to sections when we switch to mobile view that have a same parent class but are nested in two different divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I achieve this with Javascript or CSS. The simple example of the code syntax would be :

```html
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
            <section class="one">
                <p>First Line</p>
            </section>
            <section class="two">
                <p> Second line</p>
            </section>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <section class="three">
                <p>Third Line</p>
             </section>
            <section class="four">
                <p> Fourth line</p>
             </section>
      </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to swap the second and third line according to this code whenever I change to mobile view. Before that the first and second lines are in one row and third and fourth lines are in one row.
Now when we switch to mobile view everything is stacked from top to bottom but I need to change the position of second(Blue) and third(Green) lines in mobile view.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "swap"? Can you include a visual example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Your markup is not correct, you need to close the section tag.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been clearer. I hope now the problem is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You can swap the `innerHTML` of the two nodes to swap text and 'classList' to swap classes (colors). Check the code snippet below, I have used array destructing for swapping.

You can use `window.matchMedia` for swapping based on some media query.

```js
const sectionTwo = document.querySelector(".two");
const sectionThree = document.querySelector(".three");

function swapNodes(nodeOne, nodeTwo) {
  [nodeTwo.innerHTML, nodeOne.innerHTML] = [nodeOne.innerHTML, nodeTwo.innerHTML];
  [nodeTwo.classList, nodeOne.classList] = [nodeOne.classList, nodeTwo.classList];
}

if (matchMedia) {
    const mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)");
    mq.addListener(widthChange);
    widthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function widthChange(mq) {
    if(mq.matches){
    swapNodes(sectionTwo, sectionThree);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="one">
      <p>First Line</p>
    </section>
    <section class="two">
      <p> Second line</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <section class="three">
      <p>Third Line</p>
    </section>
    <section class="four">
      <p> Fourth line</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I actually don't want a button doing the job, rather I want this to be performed on media queries i.e. whenever I switch to mobile view it should automatically be swapped.

Comment: You can easily do that using the same logic as with the button click.

Comment: @JyotiBalodhi I've updated my answer please take a look, try changing the media query string and it should work accordingly.

Comment: @JyotiBalodhi You can run the code snippet and try changing to a smaller screen size, you would see the swap happening. Hope it helped!

Comment: I learn something new `window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)")`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

try to use `display: flex;`
and give a order to each div and check screen width,
base on screen with change order

check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47x2c8fg/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container > div {
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .first {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
            <section class="one">
                <p>First Line</p>
            </section>
            <section class="two">
                <p> Second line</p>
            </section>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
            <section class="three">
                <p>Third Line</p>
             </section>
            <section class="four">
                <p> Fourth line</p>
             </section>
      </div>
</div>
```